# Regex Capture Text between words, very conditionally

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Pulling my hair out at this one:

I'm trying to capture the text between these words, and invariably, I get different results.

Current code:

```
preg_match_all("/ID:([0-9A-Za-z]+)/",$data,$ids);

if (count($ids[0]) > 1) {
 $data = str_replace($ids[0][1],"",$data);
}

preg_match("/ORIG:(.*)ID:.*/",$data,$matches);

$name = $matches[1];

if (FALSE !== $heh = strpos($name,"SND BK:")) { 
 $name = substr($name,0,$heh);
}
```

Sample Data:

```
ORIG:FIRSTNAME LASTNAME ID:123123123 SND BK:TIB BANK BANK BANK DET:MEMO
ORIG:FIRSTNAME LASTNAME ID:123123123 SND BK:TIB BANK BANK BANK ID:123123123 DET:MEMO
ORIG:FIRSTNAME LASTNAME ID:123123123 DET:MEMO
```

I need to capture fully the data between `ORIG`, and `DET`. The RegEx I keep making always ends up getting one of the IDs whenever I have two IDs in the field. Sometimes `ORIG` isn't even captured at all.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i dont really understand what your trying here but if you use the following you will end up having everything between orig and det.

> (ORIG:)(.*)(DET)

Example:

```
preg_match_all('/(ORIG:)(.*)(DET)/',
              'ORIG:FIRSTNAME LASTNAME ID:123123123 SND BK:TIB BANK BANK BANK DET:MEMO',
              $result);

var_dump($result);

array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(66) "ORIG:FIRSTNAME LASTNAME ID:123123123 SND BK:TIB BANK BANK BANK DET"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "ORIG:"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(58) "FIRSTNAME LASTNAME ID:123123123 SND BK:TIB BANK BANK BANK "
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "DET"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest adding an anchor and using multiline if these data are each on one line:

```
<?php

$subject = <<<SUBJ
ORIG:FIRSTNAME FIRST LASTNAME ID:123123123 SND BK:TIB BANK BANK BANK DET:MEMO
ORIG:FIRSTNAME SECOND LASTNAME ID:123123123 SND BK:TIB BANK BANK BANK ID:123123123 DET:MEMO
ORIG:FIRSTNAME THIRD LASTNAME ID:123123123 DET:MEMO
SUBJ;

$pattern = ' /^ORIG:(.*)DET:/m';

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ORIG:FIRSTNAME FIRST LASTNAME ID:123123123 SND BK:TIB BANK BANK BANK DET:
            [1] => ORIG:FIRSTNAME SECOND LASTNAME ID:123123123 SND BK:TIB BANK BANK BANK ID:123123123 DET:
            [2] => ORIG:FIRSTNAME THIRD LASTNAME ID:123123123 DET:
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => FIRSTNAME FIRST LASTNAME ID:123123123 SND BK:TIB BANK BANK BANK 
            [1] => FIRSTNAME SECOND LASTNAME ID:123123123 SND BK:TIB BANK BANK BANK ID:123123123 
            [2] => FIRSTNAME THIRD LASTNAME ID:123123123 
        )

)
```